# How to give a user permission to start and stop a particular service using C# code

Tags: c#, service, permissions

How can I give a particular user (probably the NET SERVICE user) permission to start and stop a particular service, using C# code only.

I need the resulting code to work on everything from Windows XP to Windows 8.

[Edit]
I already have a service, which works, and an installation routine that sets folder permissions, installs the service, starts it, etc.

The service checks a url to see if there is an update, and, if so, downloads it, and starts an updater program to update the service (and terminates itself).

The updater program updates the service exe (and other needed files), and needs to restart the service.

I know from research that it is possible to give the service user (NETWORK SERVICE in this case) permission to start and stop an individual service, but I don't know the api to do it in code.

Comment: well couldn't you create a Service Account for that particular user? what do you currently have.. keep in mind `SO is not a Code Factory` you need to try somethings on your own then report back what issues you are having and others will be more than happy to help you don't expect others to do your `work for you`

Comment: I just need a few clues. What's a Service Account?

Comment: Just looked it up. Not sure it is relevant, because the question then becomes "how do I give my service Account permission to start and stop a service". Or am I missing something?

Comment: I already have a service, which works, and an installation routine that sets folder permissions, installs the service, starts it, etc. The service checks a url to see if there is an update, and, if so, downloads it, and starts an updater program to update the service (and terminates itself). The updater program updates the service exe (and other needed files), and needs to restart the service. I know from research that it is possible to give the service user (NETWORK SERVICE in this case) permission to start and stop an individual service, but I don't know the api to do it in code.

Comment: Someone (DJ KRAZE?) has marked my question down. I wish whoever it was had the courtesy to explain what they thought was wrong with it, so I could correct it, and ask better questions in future.

Comment: I've got better things to do than to mark a perfectly valid question `Down` I don't appreciate the implication

Comment: Public apology, sorry, wish whoever it was had the courtesy to say why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got a few clues from elsewhere, and managed to figure it out:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR {
    public byte revision;
    public byte size;
    public short control;
    public IntPtr owner;
    public IntPtr group;
    public IntPtr sacl;
    public IntPtr dacl;
}

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool QueryServiceObjectSecurity(IntPtr serviceHandle, 
    System.Security.AccessControl.SecurityInfos secInfo, 
    ref SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR lpSecDesrBuf, 
    uint bufSize, 
    out uint bufSizeNeeded);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool QueryServiceObjectSecurity(SafeHandle serviceHandle, 
    System.Security.AccessControl.SecurityInfos secInfo, 
    byte[] lpSecDesrBuf, 
    uint bufSize, 
    out uint bufSizeNeeded);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetServiceObjectSecurity(SafeHandle serviceHandle, 
    System.Security.AccessControl.SecurityInfos secInfos, 
    byte[] lpSecDesrBuf);

public void SetServicePermissions(string service, string username) {
    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController sc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController(service, ".");
    ServiceControllerStatus status = sc.Status;
    byte[] psd = new byte[0];
    uint bufSizeNeeded;
    bool ok = QueryServiceObjectSecurity(sc.ServiceHandle, SecurityInfos.DiscretionaryAcl, psd, 0, out bufSizeNeeded);
    if (!ok) {
        int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (err == 122 || err == 0) { // ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER
            // expected; now we know bufsize
            psd = new byte[bufSizeNeeded];
            ok = QueryServiceObjectSecurity(sc.ServiceHandle, SecurityInfos.DiscretionaryAcl, psd, bufSizeNeeded, out bufSizeNeeded);
        } else {
            throw new ApplicationException("error calling QueryServiceObjectSecurity() to get DACL for " + _name + ": error code=" + err);
        }
    }
    if (!ok)
        throw new ApplicationException("error calling QueryServiceObjectSecurity(2) to get DACL for " + _name + ": error code=" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

    // get security descriptor via raw into DACL form so ACE
    // ordering checks are done for us.
    RawSecurityDescriptor rsd = new RawSecurityDescriptor(psd, 0);
    RawAcl racl = rsd.DiscretionaryAcl;
    DiscretionaryAcl dacl = new DiscretionaryAcl(false, false, racl);

    // Add start/stop/read access
    NTAccount acct = new NTAccount(username);
    SecurityIdentifier sid = (SecurityIdentifier) acct.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
    // 0xf7 is SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG|SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG|SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS|
    // SERVICE_START|SERVICE_STOP|SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE|SERVICE_INTERROGATE
    dacl.AddAccess(AccessControlType.Allow, sid, 0xf7, InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.None);

    // convert discretionary ACL back to raw form; looks like via byte[] is only way
    byte[] rawdacl = new byte[dacl.BinaryLength];
    dacl.GetBinaryForm(rawdacl, 0);
    rsd.DiscretionaryAcl = new RawAcl(rawdacl, 0);

    // set raw security descriptor on service again
    byte[] rawsd = new byte[rsd.BinaryLength];
    rsd.GetBinaryForm(rawsd, 0);
    ok = SetServiceObjectSecurity(sc.ServiceHandle, SecurityInfos.DiscretionaryAcl, rawsd);
    if (!ok) {
        throw new ApplicationException("error calling SetServiceObjectSecurity(); error code=" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
}
```

Comment: "Modifying the DACL for a Service"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684215(v=vs.85).aspx